# How to find the Selenium Xpath locator

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to find out the xpath for selenium for the below mentioned html. There is no id for link its directing to .action. Please help me to find the xpath locator

```html
<a class="ajax-link" href="SMLogin.action"><i class=""></i><span class="hidden-tablet">Login by SM</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a fan of XPath text based search

```
.//*[.='Login by SM']
```

With `.` you can easily point to parent node. I found this much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the **xpath for "Login by SM"**, try this xpath:-

`//span[@class='hidden-tablet' and contains(text(),'Login by SM')]`